# Putting main thread to sleep has no effect on Task.Run, why?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

I designed a Window From application to see whether an `async` method still works if the main thread goes sleep. Here it is:

1- By click of Async button, `AsyncMethod` is awaited on.

2- By click of Sleep button, main thread sleeps.

I know how awaiting `AsyncMethod` works: using a state machine, it returns back to the caller but it is still working and alive. I don't have any problem with it. Simple and neat!

What I don't understand is where and by which thread this method is executed. Why putting main thread to sleep doesn't suspend `AsyncMethod`?

[image]

Here is the code:

```
        private async void btnAsync_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await AsyncMethod(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        }

        private void btnSleep_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        }
        public async Task AsyncMethod(TimeSpan duration)
        {
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
                TimeSpan ellapsed = DateTime.Now - start;
                int lastReport = 0;
                Console.Write("Working");
                while (ellapsed < duration)
                {
                    ellapsed = DateTime.Now - start;
                    if (lastReport < Math.Ceiling(ellapsed.TotalSeconds))
                    {
                        lastReport = (int)Math.Ceiling(ellapsed.TotalSeconds);
                        Console.Write(".");
                    }
                }
                Console.Write("Finished");
            });
        }
```

Comment: The task runs on a TP thread so is not affected.  What won't work is the continuation, the code *after* the await statement.  You don't have any.

Comment: @HansPassant Yes I know. My be I don't know how to test. Is there any way to run `async` method on UI thread?

Comment: @Hans Yes, by default it will run in the UI thread. `Task.Run` is the exception. Also, why do you want to run the method "asynchronously"? You aren't doing any async work. I would suggest you read Stephen Cleary's blog on async await. I think you are very confused on what "async"/"multithreaded"/"concurrent" etc means.

Comment: @Aron I am aware of what I'm doing. Indeed it may result in `synchronous` method and I don't care. I just want to see how an `async` method can run on the caller's `thread`

Comment: @Hans What you are saying makes NO SENSE. If you want a async method, you have to be doing something asynchronous. Sure you could just write `public async Task<int> Foo() { return 0; }` but that isn't an async method.

Comment: The answer to your question is right there in the documentation for [Task.Run()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh195051(v=vs.110).aspx): _**"Queues the specified work to run on the thread pool"**_. Questioners are expected to do at least some research before posting a question, and explaining what research they've done, so that answers can be more than just reading the documentation to you. Please work at constructing your questions more carefully and usefully.

Answer (score 1):

> What I don't understand is where and by which thread this method is
>   executed. Why putting main thread to sleep doesn't suspend
>   AsyncMethod?

This method is executed by a thread from the CLR's managed threads pool. If this was true, then the main thread in your application, which is responsible for your UI would be frozen, while it was working on the execution of you async method and the UI exprerience wouldn't be the best one.

Furthermore, this is the purpose of `Task.Run` method. According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.run(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Queues the specified work to run on the ThreadPool and returns a task
>   or Task handle for that work.

Comment: But there are lots of places stated that an `async` method may not run a new thread. There is no guarantee

Comment: Is there any case that can make an `async` method without using `Task.Run` ?

Comment: @Hans I would actually say that `Task.Run` is specificially FOR running on a different thread. In almost every case (excluding Task.Run, the code runs on the same thread, often at great pains).

Comment: @Hans Yes. Take almost every other implementation of a method that returns a `Task`. In fact I would say that you should as a beginner NEVER use `Task.Run` and NEVER use `Thread.Sleep` if you plan to use async await.

Comment: @Micky i choose my words carefully. "As a beginner (on modern hardware)" you would be very unlikely to be CPU bound. For those who are CPU bound, it is very likely that you know how to recognise you are CPU bound, and when you understand that, you'd know the advantages and disadvantages of Threading. At which point the advice would not apply to you. Calculating a Mandelbrot (on SMP hardware) would of course apply. However similarly Calculating a Mandelbrot on AMP hardware would not, but then clearly if you are following my reasoning, this does not apply to you.

Comment: @Micky That isn't a compute operation. Its not even an I/O operation. I can't remember the last time I saw a problem on SO which wasn't solvable in P-Time. Seriously, your CPU is currently INSANELY fast.